Issue with Uploading Files using React and Node.js hosted on cPanel
File upload stopped working (gives timeout, no error) since 11 Oct, without deploying anything. We have discussed with the hosting support team but they said that on their side everything seems fine. We checked the php.ini config file, every value is higher than 130KB! :)
We have updated the axios, express libraries..., changed multer library to formidable...
At the end we have started to implement a very simple code snippet for testing which also gives timeout if file is greater than 130KB.
This guy has the same issue we have:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cpanel/comments/1fy3nb7/issue_with_uploading_files_over_100kb_using_react/
Anybody knows what is happening? or what could we check?
Thanks in advance

I have found the problem, unfortunately for you, it's a server issue, but maybe if you contact your hosting they will be able to fix it.
The problem is as I suspected with Phusion Passenger version==6.0.23 in the following link you can see someone who has already reported the incident, but has no answers yet (I will post mine soon) -» https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2569
The solution I have implemented for this on my cPanel servers is to go to EasyApache 4 and downgrade the modules to ruby24-mod_passenger and remove the ruby27-mod_passenger versions with their dependencies, this will force Phusion Passenger to use version 6.0.7
With these simple steps we will have the servers working correctly again. If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to contact me. I hope you can sort it out on your end.
Kid regards, Harold.

The host support team solved the problem yesterday but didn't provide an explanation. I am sure that they have upgraded/downgraded some libraries as you did.
So whoever is struggling with this issue: contact your hosting support team.
